# how to find the string that is empty or null in many string quickly

Tags: java

I have several strings, like id, name, age, etc, I want to do a check to make sure they are not empty or null, if is empty or null, throw an exception with the error message, eg: "id can not be empty or null"

This is what I'm doing now, but I need to check them one by one if the first if condition is correct, is there a way to make the code simple and easier?

```
if(（StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(age)) == false) {
   if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id) == false) {
     throw Exception("...")
   }
   else if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name) == false) {
     throw Exception("...")
   }
   ..
}
```

Comment: Is `name`, `age` etc in a POJO?

Comment: Are you using Spring or any other third party libraries (including JSON validators)?

Comment: I would suggest using wrapper for ID, Name, ... to make it typesafe and add there the validation on creating an instance. See example here: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These double negative do negativly impact the readability of your code. For example `if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id) == false)`, which can be replaced easily with `id.isEmpty()`. Applying this will translate to:

```java
public void verify() throws IllegalStateException {
    if(name == null || id == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("not initialized");
    if(name.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("name is empty");
    if(id.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("id is empty");
}
```

Another approach would be to just throw an error if any of the strings is empty:

```java
public void verify() throws IllegalStateException {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("object was empty: " + toString());
}

private boolean isEmpty() {
    return id.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Person{");
    str.append("id: " + id + " ");
    str.append("name: " + name + " ");
    str.append("}");
    return str.toString();
}
```

Now, if the error is thrown you can examine which variable was responsible for it (if you want).

That said, the best solution would be to redesign your object structure. Testing for `null` should not be a thing when using your own written classes. One of the few justifications is while using a low-level API but then all the null stuff should never be seen outside the corresponding function calls. Your functions should never return null and in turn, expect null as a parameter or use null as a value for checking something. Null indicates a programmer error (e.g. a function was called incorrectly), a flaw in your program. Because of that, the NullPointerException will be thrown as an [unchecked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html). So in most cases just don't handle the case when null is given as an argument.

Another thing to consider is that such a verify method might be redundant when you use setters. Always keep your member variables in a valid state. For example, a real person can not exist without age and an id (which should be given automatically). So if you really want to check if the input is empty and throw an error if so I would suggest:

```java
class Person {

    private String id, name, age;

    public Person(String name, String age) {

        if(name.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("name and age cannot be empty!");

        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if(name.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("name cannot be empty!");
        else
            this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        if(age.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("age cannot be empty!");
        else
            this.age = age;
    }
}
```

This is based on the idea that "id, name, age" are member variables of a class.